# How to set or lappend at nth level in dictionary?

Tags: tcl

```
dict set X 1 2 3 4
>> X = 1 {2 {3 4}}
```

1. Now after doing some calcuation, it find that 5 and 6 should next two value and it is needed insert `5` and `6` in the dict such that `X = 1 {2 {3 {4 {5 6}}}}`. How to do it with native dict one liner commands? `dict set 1 2 3 4 5 6` is not helping in this case.

```
dict set X 1 2 3 4 
dict set X a b c d 
>> X = 1 {2 {3 4}} a {b {c d}}
```

2. In the case above, how to lappend `x` with `4` such that `4 x` gets returned when executing `dict get $X 1 2 3`, with native one liner dict commands? `dict lappend X 1 2 3 x` is not helping in this case.

**Please be noted that `X` should be set to initial value and only after that need to add elements in the manners asked above using dict one liner commands.**

Comment: There isn't arbitrary lappending to things deep inside a dict as a single command because there are syntactic ambiguities that could only be resolved by making more common use cases really ugly. Because of that, you need to use a composite solution with `dict update` and/or `dict with`. Or do things manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Adding a new nested key

When you start with

```
tcl8.6.8> dict set X 1 2 3 4
1 {2 {3 4}}
```

...you're specifying that the value under the nested key `3` is a single value and not itself a dictionary.

If you try to add a nested key below `3`, then Tcl will try to create a dictionary for the value of `3` but it cannot successfully convert the existing value `4` into a dict.

```
tcl8.6.8> dict set X 1 2 3 8 9
missing value to go with key
```

The above error is complaining that there is no value present for the key `4`.  This is equivalent to trying `dict get 4`.

The solution is to intitialize `4` as a nested key with an empty list as its value, instead of just the value under `3`.  Once `4` is a valid key with a corresponding value, then you're allowed to replace the value with something else.

```
tcl8.6.8> unset X
tcl8.6.8> dict set X 1 2 3 4 {}
1 {2 {3 {4 {}}}}
tcl8.6.8> dict set X 1 2 3 4 5 6
1 {2 {3 {4 {5 6}}}}
```

#### Appending to nested keys

The `dict lappend` command does not append to a list under a nested key. When you say `dict lappend X key1 key2 val_to_append`, you are appending both `key2` and `val_to_append` to the value of `key1`.   Only the first argument after the dictvarname is recognized as a key.  The remaining arguments are all values to append to the list.

To append to a value under a nested key, you can use `dict with`.
For example.

```
tcl8.6.8> dict set X 1 2 3 4
1 {2 {3 4}}
tcl8.6.8> dict with X 1 2 {lappend 3 x y}
4 x y
tcl8.6.8> puts $X
1 {2 {3 {4 x y}}}
```

Comment: Alternately, `dict set X 1 2 3 [dict create 4 {5 6}]`

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for you time but basically following is the requirement: I do have this `1 {2 {3 4}}` and now I need to have this `1 {2 {3 {4 {5 6}}}}` using native dict one liner only. And similairly I have this `1 {2 {3 4}} a {b {c d}}` and want to have this `1 {2 {3 {4 x}}} a {b {c d}}` using native dict one liner command.

Comment: Please explain what qualifies as a native dict one liner command...and why is this a critical requirement???
Appending to a nested key's list in your example can be done with `dict with X 1 2 {lappend 3 x}`.   That's all native Tcl and in one line.  What's wrong with that?

Comment: Wast trying to run script and storing data in dict. I was facing issue trying to lappend new data in nested dict. Here I have just put all my query in simple way with constraints to imitate the issue I faced.

Comment: I don't see why `dict set X 1 2 3 [dict create 4 {5 6}]` and `dict with X 1 2 {lappend 3 x}` don't satisfy you for an answer.  Both of those are native Tcl commands that fit on one line and also work with the initial conditions you specify.    Please explain.